# Can I access a windows share from Win7 without turning on file sharing?

Tags: windows-7, network-shares

I have a Win7 machine that I want to be able to access a folder that is shared out from a XP box but I don't want it to be able to share any of it's files. I seem to remember being able to do this on XP boxes (IIRC you don't have to enable file sharing unless you want to share your files). From what little poking I've done I can't see how to enable this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an administrative share

```
\\mycomputername\c$
```

It should prompt you for a login.

Comment: If it prompts me for a login, something is wrong (the shared folder is set up to not require it)

Comment: It's C$, not $C

Comment: typo corrected.

Answer (score 0):

You need the file sharing service running to share files, even administrative ones.  You can use the default \computername\c$ to access anything on the C drive, and similar for D$, E$ and so on and so forth.  I don't believe you need to turn on file sharing on the Windows 7 host to access these shares.

Comment: Well, the immediate problem went away when I turned on sharing, set the workgroup and used the other computer's name rather than IP (I'd think that wold bypass the workgroup issue) so one or more of those was at fault. - I'm guessing not the sharing because it seems to work even now that I turn it off.

Comment: Workgroups only work for Windows 7, so setting the workgroup probably didn't change anything.

Comment: @Velociraptor: Workgroups have existed for a **lot** longer than that (windows 3.11 was "windows for workgroups") Might you be thinking of homegroups?

Comment: I was absolutely thinking of homegroups. So much for reading comprehension.